# Explode by special character ·

Tags: php

I have string like this : 
`Suède · Slovénie`

I need to explode it by `·`  i have tried various solutions like :

```
preg_split("/[?·]/",strip_tags($single->children(2)->outertext))

explode(chr(149), strip_tags($single->children(2)->outertext)); 

explode(utf8_encode('·'),strip_tags($single->children(2)->outertext));

explode('·',strip_tags($single->children(2)->outertext));
```

But none of solutions works for me! can any one please let me know?

Comment: hat charset are you using? `è` in Utf-8 are two bytes  (0xC3, 0xA8), `explode()`, like other PHP string functions, works on a byte base

Comment: Preg_split space dot space? I mean dot as in any char

Comment: I think you can teach the `preg_*` function to operate on Unicode strings properly (I'm assuming UTF-8) using the `u` flag, so `preg_split('/?·]/u',..)` could do the job, too. However, Marcin's suggestion to use `mb_split()` is much better, because it's more expressive.

Comment: your code works fine for me http://ideone.com/j4tH6w

Comment: are you using DOMDocument ? it's seems to be a character encoding problem

Comment: @PedroLobito using simplehtmldom

Answer (score 4):

You shall rather use [mb_split()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php):

```
  var_dump(mb_split('·', 'Suède · Slovénie'));
```

gives

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "Suède "
  [1]=>
  string(10) " Slovénie"
}
```

Comment: ' · ' could be better, save the trimming iteration

Comment: It wouldn't really. You do not know how many whitespaces are used there.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work on the given string, but maybe not on all your strings.

```
preg_split("/\b (\W+) \b/", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file is using Utf-8 most likely. In Utf-8 `·` consists of two bytes (0xC2, 0xB7) such an expression like `"/[?·]/"` will break on either of these bytes. Instead you have to use the `u` modifier to use Utf-8 mode:

```
$ php -r 'print_r(preg_split("/[?·]/u", "Suède·Slovénie"));'
Array
(
    [0] => Suède
    [1] => Slovénie
)
```

Even better is using `mb_split()` the multibyte aware splitting function, but that is not always available.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using `simplehtmldom` and it's not encoding the characters properly, use `str_get_html` as follows:

```
//mb_convert_encoding will try to detect the `$html` encoding and convert it to `UTF-8`
$html =  str_get_html(mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents("http://somesite.com"), 'auto', 'UTF-8'));
```

then, you can simply use:

```
explode('·',strip_tags($single->children(2)->outertext));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, `&middot;` = · and we need to just put that htmlentity.

```
explode('&middot;',$str);
```